# Proportional to Gamma means the posterior is gamma

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, posterior, gamma-distribution, conjugate-prior

I'm reading through these lecture notes on posteriors and conjugate priors.
https://web.stanford.edu/class/stats200/Lecture20.pdf

In particular, it asserts that: "This is proportional to the PDF of the Gamma(s + α, n + β)
distribution, so the posterior distribution of Λ must be Gamma(s + α, n + β)." on page 20-4.

Why is this allowed? Does this just generally work for data drawn from poisson with a Gamma prior?

Comment: This refers to the concept of a kernel of a distribution, which determines its shape. All that is missing is a proportionality constant that ensures that the density integrates to one. So the argument works for any proper density.

Comment: Thanks. So when calculating posteriors, is it simply enough then to find p(x|theta)p(theta) as long as I pick a conjugate prior? Since I know there will be an analytical solution to p(x), as in, it will integrate to some constant that can be ignored.

Comment: Yes. It should also work even if you do not pick a conjugate prior, although there will then be relatively few cases in which analytical solutions are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a probability density $f$ is known up to a multiplicative constant,
$$f(x)\propto \tilde f(x)\qquad\forall x\in\mathfrak X$$
meaning that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $f(x)=c\tilde f(x)$, the constant $c$ is determined by the constraint that $f(\cdot)$ is a probability density:
$$c^{-1} = \int_\mathfrak X \tilde f(x)\,
\text dx$$

See some of the many related questions:

- [Why is posterior density proportional to prior density times likelihood function?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/64364/7224)
- [Deriving the proportionality constant for the posterior distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/324009/7224)
- [Basic question on proportionality in Bayesian Inference for Normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/379949/7224)
- [Proportionality in Bayesian Models: What Is Absorbed?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/44450/7224)
- [Normalizing constant in Bayes theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12112/7224)